# How can I crawl ActiveX contents in Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, activex

I'm on the task that crawl specific web pages (with Internet Explorer).
In some pages contain kinds of grid table, and when I checked it's HTML source. There are no table related data except space for that table. Seems like contents in the table is cannot be crawled within HTML source.

When I checked it's HTML source, there are nothing but strings like `[object Object]` or some random string which written in alphabets and numbers.

Also all I can get from that source is that it is called WiseGrid (I also installed `WiseGrid` activeX for sign in.)
And when I search other word for checking source table, it only changes strange long text.

Is there any general way to get data from that docs?

Sorry for really unfriendly explanation. I cannot upload while code here(It's table contain more than 1000 data and it's html contents are not-interpretable.)

Comment: Reading out ActiveX plugins can be hard depending on how it's build. One thing to consider might be making screenshots of the page, and then using OCR to parse the pages.

Comment: Can you find a publicly available example to share?

Comment: @Ferrybig Yeah, seems it is the only way, but button for navigating table is also in ActiveX and I need to control the page. But image inspection is good idea.

Comment: @QHarr I don't think I can find public example for this case. I cannot find anything from the web except for my business related code. What I can tell you is just it is a `WiseGrid`(I didn't hear that before)